# « Une nouveauté qui le restera toujours de l’avoir été un jour »

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, pronoms

Cette construction de phrase me rend très perplexe.

« Non, toi, ce que tu espères toujours c’est de tomber sur une vraie nouveauté, sur une nouveauté qui le restera toujours de l’avoir été un jour. » Italo Calvino, Si une nuit d’hiver un voyageur, éditions Gallimard, 2015, pg. 14.

Après avoir demandé de l’aide à Google Traduction, je crois que le sens de cette phrase c’est que cette nouveauté dont on parle aura toujours la qualité d’avoir été une nouveauté. Pourtant, pourquoi a-t-on mis un « le » devant « restera » ?

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que les deux « le » réfèrent à « une nouveauté ». La première partie de la proposition relative (« qui le restera toujours ») est ainsi équivalente à « qui restera toujours une nouveauté ».

D'autre part, [la traduction anglaise du roman](https://www.coerll.utexas.edu/ecomma/node/18) se lit :

> No, you hope always to encounter true newness, which, having been new once, will continue to be so.

À mon avis, c'est assez proche de mon interprétation.

Comment: @LPH I agree with your analysis in (2); to be precise, I think it better grasps the semantic function of the object. I don't think (4) is necessarily helpful: this is the exact text that I took from an official translation, and anyway, the English can only serve as a reference when the book was originally in Italian.

Comment: As to the case when "le" is omitted, the interpretation that you gave is the exact one that I was going for, but I suppose as a whole, it made slightly more sense to me in the early morning when I wrote the answer than it does now.

Comment: yes, the interpretation is the same but the diction is very poor, as I see it.

Comment: The diction as in my phrasing (which I can adjust) or as in that of the translation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112424/discussion-between-maroon-and-lph).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Maroon answer:

> Pourtant, pourquoi a-t-on mis un « le » devant « restera » ?

Parce qu'il faut obligatoirement un attribut du sujet au verbe *rester* qui est ici clairement un verbe d'état.

Comment: Ah, merci! Ça rend les choses beaucoup plus claires.